# Inserting row error, incorrect syntax near '<'

Tags: sql-server

I've never used SQL Servre before so this is completely new to me.

I have the following insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO 
    [dbo].[WEB_static_pages]([url], [template], [title], [metadesc],[metakey])
VALUES
    (<url, varchar(255), "test">,
     <template, varchar(255), "test.php">,
     <title, nvarchar(255), "test title">,
     <metadesc, text, "test meta">,
     <metakey, text, "test meta key">)
GO
```

The following has three 'tooltip' warnings though in SQL Server Management Studio:

> Incorrect syntax near '<'" and "varchar is not a recognised built in function name

Can anyone suggest what the issue is here? How can I reformat my statement to suit SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: You can't mix the table definition and inserting into the table. There are so many examples of an insert in SQL server. Just look for 10 seconds

Comment: @juergend I struggled to find any which used the syntax in my question, this is the syntax generated by SQL Server Management studio so it's fair to assume that is what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

When inserting values using SQL Server, you need only specifies the actual data you want inserted in the `VALUES` clause.  So use a comma-separated list of values in your case, and wrap it in parentheses:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[WEB_static_pages]
           ([url]
           ,[template]
           ,[title]
           ,[metadesc]
           ,[metakey])
 VALUES (
        'test',
        'test.php',
        'test title',
        'test meta',
        'test meta key')
```

Comment: it would be better if you replace "(double quote) with '(single quote).

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite it like this, it should work:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[WEB_static_pages]
           ([url]
           ,[template]
           ,[title]
           ,[metadesc]
           ,[metakey])
     VALUES
           ('test'
           ,'test.php'
           ,'test title'
           ,'test meta'
           ,'test meta key')
GO
```